# Type mismatch error in initialization of HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>

Tags: java, hashmap

Since using generics is a good practice in initialing HashMap and the following initialization works fine:

```
Map<String,String> x = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Why do I have a type mismatch error in initialing the nested HashMaps:

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> y = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Comment: use like this. Map<String,Map<String,String>> y = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();

Comment: Why do you need/think you need this data structure?

Comment: I use this data structure for generalization of my SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with declaration please replace above declaration with below line.

```
Map<String,HashMap<String,String>> y = new HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>>();
```

If you look at exception you will get an better idea.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<String,HashMap<String,String>> to Map<String,Map<String,String>>
```

It matches exact type.
When your given type it might be exact same type. Instead of `Map<String,String>` you to use `HashMap<String,String>`

If you want to try another thing please try with below line as well.

```
Map<String,Map<String,String>> y = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
```